# Changing the css sprite position of an icon tag

Tags: html, css, tags, icons

I am trying to change the background position of the icon tag on hover. How can I do this if it's in an icon tag instead of the a tag?

The html icon tag is:

```
<a class="info" href="#"><i class="tag"></i> Info</a>
<a class="info" href="#"><i class="other_tag"></i> Other Info</a>
```

The CSS is:

```
.tag {
    background: url('images/tag.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.other_tag {
    background: url('images/other_tag.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.info {
    color: #6a9d2b;
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.info:hover {
    background-position: 0 -13px;
    color: #4a6e1e;
}
```

The icons width are actually 13px in width and 31px in height.

Comment: I put an answer but I'm not sure if it's what you are asking. If so, just tell me and I will delete the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the nested rules like that:

```
.info:hover .tag {
  /* Put a different background position */
}

.info:hover .other-tag {
  /* Put a different background position */
}
```